# The last line of this python program uses both " and ' but I don't know why

Tags: python

Ok on [this link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex8.html) it shows the last line of output that has ' around everything except the third sentence and I do not know why. This bothered me at the beginning and thought it was just a weird mistake but its on the "extra credit" so now I am even more curious.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `%r` formatter prints the argument in the form you may use in source code, which, for strings, means that it is quote-delimited and escaped. For boolean values, this is just `True` or `False`. To print the string as it is, use `%s` instead.

```
>>> print '%s' % '"Hello, you\'re"'         
"Hello, you're"
>>> print '%r' % '"Hello, you\'re"'                        
'"Hello, you\'re"'
```

Comment: I normally don't, but the answer isn't that obvious, so I have chosen to explain my answer clearly.

Comment: its not homework. this is all voluntary. I'm just trying to learn on my own before I start it in school.

Comment: Okay then. I've removed the `homework` tag that Gabriel added earlier. Gabriel, if you are not sure that something is homework, err on the side of caution and do not add a `homework` tag.

Comment: @Delan: seemed obvious, especially after mention of the extra credit:)

Comment: 'Extra credit' is a section on the Python tutorial page that the OP linked.

Comment: This is "Learn Python the Hard Way" - it's intended as a self-study course with exercises, so any "homework" is self-assigned. Nobody is trying to get an easy pass on a course and giving a direct answer is reasonable IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

python's `repr()` function, which is invoked by interpolating the `%r` formatting directive, has the approximate effect of printing objects the way they would appear in source code.

There are several ways to format strings in python source, using single or double quotes, with backslash escapes or as raw strings, as simple, single line strings or multi line strings (in any combination).  Python picks only two ways to format strings, as single or double quoted, single line strings with escapes instead of raw.

Python makes a crude attempt at picking a minimal format, with a slight bias in favor of the single quote version (since that would be one fewer keystrokes on most keyboards).

The rules are very simple.  If a string contains a single quote, but no double quotes, python prints the string as it would appear in python source if it were double quoted, Otherwise it uses single quotes.

Some examples to illustrate.  Note for simplicity all of the inputs use triple quotes to avoid backslash escapes.

```
>>> ''' Hello world '''
' Hello world '
>>> ''' "Hello world," he said. '''
' "Hello world," he said. '
>>> ''' You don't say? '''
" You don't say? "
>>> ''' "Can't we all just get along?" '''
' "Can\'t we all just get along?" '
>>>
```

Comment: This is more informative than the accepted answer, and actually addresses the "around everything except the third sentence" bit.